# Clojure returns the list of all pairs in seq that have key as their first element

Tags: clojure, seq

I need to define a function called 
(get-all-pairs key seq)

It returns the list of all pairs in seq that have key as their first element. If no pairs match, then the empty list is returned.

For example,if I def pets

```
(def pets
   '((cat 1) (dog 1) (fish 1) (cat 2) (fish 2))
)
```

`(get-all-pairs 'cat pets)` returns `((cat 1) (cat 2))`, and `(get-all-pairs 'bird pets)` returns `'()`.

Here is my try:

```
(defn get-all-pairs [key seq]
  (cond
    (= key (first(first(seq)))) (cons (first seq) 
                                      (get-all-pairs key (rest seq)))
    :else '()))
```

But it doesnot work. If I call it, it messages as follow:

```
#'proj2.proj2/pets
=> (get-all-pairs 'cat pets)
ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  proj2.proj2/get-all-pairs (proj2.clj:20)
```

I don't know where the problem is. How to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

The immediate error is because you have too many parens in your definition: `(first (first (seq)))` should just be `(first (first seq))`. Once you fix that, your function should run to completion, but give you the wrong answer: think about whether `()` is really what you want in your `else` case.

Once you've worked out your by-hand recursive approach, try to figure out what is going on in this solution:

```
(defn get-all-pairs [k pairs]
  (filter #(= k (first %)) pairs))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! After reading your comment, I realize that my :else case is wrong. But I meet a new problem now. If I try: (cond
   (= key (first(first seq))) (cons (first seq) (get-all-pairs key (rest seq)))  
   (not= key (first (first seq))) (get-all-pairs key (rest seq))
    
   :else '()
)  It turns out to be a stackoverflow error message. How can I finish this recursive approach?

Comment: Well, if you look closer you'll see you don't actually have a base case at all: either the first key is equal to `key`, in which case you recur, or it's not, in which case you still recur; you have an `:else` clause, but it only runs if `x` is neither equal to `key` nor not-equal to it (ie, never).

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but sort of over-thinking this one. [For](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/for) allows you to abstract away many of the things you are attempting to do manually. In this case, we can generate a seq and iteratively use an if expression with :when.

```
(defn get-all-pairs [animal L]
  (for [k L
        :when (= animal (first k))]
    k))
```